# Exception when comparing Guid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to get a list of all categories that contain a site with a specific ID. Below is the scaffold generated method i slightly modified.

```
        [HttpGet("Categories/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategoriesSite([FromRoute] Guid id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            // This line throws the error
            var categories = await _context.Categories.Where(o => o.Site.Id.Equals(id)).ToListAsync();

            if (categories == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(categories);
        }
```

Unfortunately when i run this it throws the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Guid' of method 'Boolean Equals(System.Guid)'
```

Entities are very simple:

```
    public class Category
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Site Site { get; set; }
    }

    public class Site
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to pass the Guid into the GetCategoriesSite method. The error sounds like you are not passing in a Guid, and it's a null value.

Comment: its a GET call from postman http://localhost:8080/api/Categories/32f770d6-ce84-4325-42ea-08d529984e6d

Comment: Which line is causing the exception to occur?

Comment: @Darthchai check the edited method, i marked the line that is apparently not behaving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a bug in EF Core, check this [issue](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/499) on github. Workaround with replacing of `Equals()` with `==` operator worked fine for me:

```
var categories = await _context.Categories.Where(o => o.Site.Id == id).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Sweet jehovas witness that was it. I bloody pulled my hair out thinking it was something stupid that i did.